# How can I increase the size of textarea via javascript doubleclick?

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea

I am trying to create a trigger in my form such that if someone double-clicks the empty part of textarea, it increases the height. I am trying the below code but it doesn't work. 
What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_details" class="fields">
<label id="label_details" for="input_details" >Details</label><br/>
<textarea id="input_details" class="" name="details" disabled="disabled" >Customer can look more.</textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#input_details').dblclick(function(){
    $('#input_details').animate({height: '+=50'}, 500);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hejr3Lve/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that disabled form elements don't fire mouse events.
Your code would work if it were applied to a text area that wasn't in a disabled state.

One possible solution is to surround the text area in a container, which you animate instead, and have the text area set to fill the container.

An example:

```js
$('.container').dblclick(function(){
    $('.container').animate({height: '+=50'}, 500);
});
```

```css
.container{
  height:100px;
}

#input_details{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_details" class="fields">
<label id="label_details" for="input_details" >Details</label><br/>
<div class="container">
  <textarea id="input_details" class="" name="details" disabled="disabled" >Customer can look more.</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a div around the textare and bind the event to this div.
It´s not possible to do this with a disabled textarea.

Example: (binded to your div)

```
$('#div_details').dblclick(function(){
    $('#input_details').animate({height: '+=50'}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've disabled your textarea, which means the double click event is never triggered.

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element. (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled)

Once you remove the `disabled` attribute, you'll see it starts working. I'd suggest to not use a `textarea` if you're not planning to make the element interactive.